# SQL Server 2008: Is there a better (server side) replacement for Bulk Insert?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

The TLDR version:
Bulk Insert will tell you how many rows it affected. It will NOT tell you how many rows it TRIED to affect, or how many failed. The problem with this is intuitively obvious, and I want to know if there is a more reliable way of uploading from text files, keeping the code inside the server.

The Full Version: I have an application which needs to periodically upload text data files into SQL Server tables. For some wild and crazy reason I thought to put this in a stored procedure to make it part of an abstraction layer rather than have the front end application write directly to the tables.

As with most SQL Server scripting I spent my usual share of time bashing my head against a brick wall to get it to work at all. (With no small amount of help from searching past posts on this site and others.)

Will Bulk Insert read a header row to determine which fields to write to? Nope, I have to either use a Format File (and hope that the table structure / order never changes) or use a staging table containing only the columns in the data file. The staging table receives the data prior to copying it to the real table.

What if you omit a single column in the target table (even one which has a default) and don't use a Format File? You get the oh-so-self-explanatory error message "Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)"." Using the aforementioned staging table, omitting any columns which aren't in the data source, gets around this.

That's fine, I can live with that. It's not the scary part. This is.

If the staging table still has any fields which are defined as NOT NULL, but a data source row is null for that column, you do not get an error. Based on my tests, if you have (say) 5 rows of data and row 3 is missing data in a NOT NULL field, then you won't get an error but will get the message "4 rows updated". Which is all fine and dandy if you're expecting 5 rows and do a cross-check against the number of rows affected to make sure that the expected number is there, but these files will be of varying lengths and Bulk Insert will not tell you how many rows it actually read. Worse, in some cases a missing field in one row will prevent the following (valid) row from uploading as well.

The obvious solution? Remove the NOT NULL constraints from the staging table and handle any null exceptions in the interface between the staging table and the real table. However... my concern is that this piece of cr...ode may do the same thing in other circumstances that I haven't come across yet. That is, read a row, fail to write it to the staging table, and not throw an exception so that nobody knows that data is missing until they go looking for it and find that it just ain't there. Even Access has better text import options than this.

My question, then, is... is there a better (more reliable) way of handling uploads of variable row length text files to SQL Server without having to rely on the front end app to do it?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Well, you are trying to do a `BULK INSERT`, it shouldn't come as a surprise that you don't have a lot of control over how it does it. If you want more control (for example using a Data Flow task from SSIS), you are gonna gain it through a hit on performance, it really is up to you

Comment: It's not a question of how it does it. It's purely a question of "It sometimes DOESN'T do it, and more to the point it doesn't TELL you that it doesn't do it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET's `SqlBulkCopy` would give you more control when transferring data to the staging table, and still provide great performance.

Now, considering you want all the logic on the server itself, maybe the following strategy might work for you:

Keep the staging table without any sort of restrictions that may make your process fail. Have additional columns on it created, such as an `IsValid`, plus an `ErrorMessage` column.

Then write a stored procedure that will validate the data on each row, checking for conditions, missing values, length of text, any custom business rules you may want to enforce.

Each validation could be a single `UPDATE` statement to the staging table, setting `IsValid` or an `ErrorCode` plus an `ErrorMessage`, having the condition on its `WHERE` clause, for example.

Once all validation `UPDATE` statements have run, you should have a subset of rows that are valid for importing (those marked as IsValid) and others on which you can clearly identify the cause of the problem and log or inform the user on a row by row basis.

That strategy proved to be quite effective under scenarios where invalid data is imported frequently.

Now, if you are going to be running multiple import processes in parallel, then you may need to divide your imported data in the staging table according to some "process identifier" and possibly index it, to avoid locking between the processes when running the mass validations on the data.

Comment: Thanks Pablo. What you're describing (in the later part) sounds a lot like what I was thinking of when I said that I was looking at "(handling) any null exceptions in the interface between the staging table and the real table". My main concern is in the bit before that; certainly removing the Not Nulls SHOULD remove any issues with missing data & invalid data types I could handle by expanding your idea by making all fields in Staging an NVarChar. My concern is the step before that though; I can never be 100% certain that all rows uploaded. I'll take a look at SQLBulkCopy too. Thanks again.

Comment: I see. Well, in that case SqlBulkCopy will give you that certainty. However, note that error handling with it is quite primitive. Meaning, the process would fail if an error occurs. 
So in order to prevent that you'd have to dump data in batches, say of 1k or 10k rows depending on your data size. And when a batch fails you could process rows individually, or subdivide the batch kind of like a binary search for the error, and that kind of thing.
That's the main problem. These high performance features can have that performance mainly by lack of logging and validations.

Comment: For example, here's an attempt at solving that problem: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/387465/Retrieving-failed-records-after-an-SqlBulkCopy-exc

Comment: Many thanks again Pablo. I'd actually be OK with the whole batch failing as long as the user can be told WHERE and WHY it failed. What I was thinking if I were to go down the SQLBulkCopy route within the client is that I'd be able to load the thing up and pre-validate (or fail) the rows within the client app (which will be a VB.Net app) before actually passing it back to SQL server. I'm philosophically opposed to that because I'd rather keep all of the processing code on the server but it may be the only practical way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class in System.Data.Client should give you more control and feedback.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Pablo beat you to it but as I said to him I'll take a look at that in case I do have to go client side for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would still use SSIS for this even though handling ragged files is still difficult with it.  It gives you a lot of control and good performance.

Comment: Thanks Cade, but the intention is really to have a stored procedure that the front end can call by simply passing the filename to it. (I may not have made that clear enough, sorry.) As I mentioned in a comment above I'm not so much after control of the process (I'm happy enough to use the staging table / update to the main table approach), it's really just a question of reliability. The fact that rows of data can just disappear into the ether with no warning if Bulk Insert doesn't care for them is one that I find a bit disturbing.

Comment: @AlanK I guess you could BULK INSERT into a table of a single column of varchar(max) - then process...  And although that can be attractive, I would still personally look at SSIS (you can start an agent job from a stored procedure), because it simply lets you load a lot more data since it's stream oriented (you'd probably have to batch parsing 5m rows of text lines in pure T-SQL) and it gives you a lot of flexibility.  I wish BULK INSERT had more options, but part of the issue is that SQL will always be more set-oriented and a lot of ETL requires some serious non-set processing.

Comment: Hmmm, agent job from the sproc. That's something I'll definitely explore. I haven't spent a lot of time in SSIS yet. Thanks again Cade.

Comment: @AlanK It's a whole thing, but you can do pretty cool things with it.  If you can do it in pure T-SQL, do it.  But it's got a place - but there are techniques it can do - like updates - where you still want to let it insert only the rows to be updated into a staging table using the faster bulk loading option on that destination and run a T-SQL step because you don't want to run individual UPDATE statements.  But being able to split the stream and do different things with different rows is pretty awesome.